# Running Script on button click

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to run an external Python script on a button click. I think I almost have it working although it runs the external script as soon as I run the GUI class itself. I need it to run the script when the button is clicked. I think I almost have it, could someone guide me as to what I need to change.

I have written a function called parseCanonical(): and this is where I am trying to set up the button click so that I can run the external script.

```
# import Statements
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from reportViewerWindow import Ui_reportViewerWindow
import os
import CanonicalAddressesParser

# Main Class that holds User Interface Objects
class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    # Function for Opening Report Viewer Window From Main Window by clicking View Reports button
    def openReportViewer(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_reportViewerWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()



    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(834, 428)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        # Sim Card Button
        self.simCardButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.simCardButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 200, 211, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.simCardButton.setFont(font)
        self.simCardButton.setObjectName("simCardButton")

        # Call Logs Button
        self.callLogButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.callLogButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 300, 211, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.callLogButton.setFont(font)
        self.callLogButton.setObjectName("callLogButton")

        # SMS Button
        self.smsButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.smsButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 250, 211, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smsButton.setFont(font)
        self.smsButton.setObjectName("smsButton")

        # Canonical Address Button
        self.canonicalAddressesButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 150, 211, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setFont(font)
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setObjectName("canonicalAddressesButton")

        # Main Window Label
        self.windowMainLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.windowMainLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 20, 423, 32))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.windowMainLabel.setFont(font)
        self.windowMainLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.windowMainLabel.setObjectName("windowMainLabel")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 110, 291, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        # Combo Box settings
        self.ViewDataCB = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.ViewDataCB.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 150, 231, 22))
        self.ViewDataCB.setObjectName("ViewDataCB")
        self.ViewDataCB.addItem("")
        self.ViewDataCB.addItem("")
        self.ViewDataCB.addItem("")
        self.ViewDataCB.addItem("")
        self.ViewDataCB.addItem("")
        self.ViewDataCB.addItem("")

        # # View Evidence Button
        self.viewEvidenceButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.viewEvidenceButton.setFont(font)
        self.viewEvidenceButton.setObjectName("viewEvidenceButton")



        # Label for evidence viewer
        self.evidenceViewingLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.evidenceViewingLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(660, 120, 141, 16))
        self.evidenceViewingLabel.setObjectName("evidenceViewingLabel")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 320, 141, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")
        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")
        self.actionOpen_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen_2.setObjectName("actionOpen_2")
        self.actionExit_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit_2.setObjectName("actionExit_2")

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    # Function that sets the text on all the UI Buttons
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "SQLite DB Android Parser"))
        self.simCardButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sim Card"))
        self.callLogButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Call Logs"))
        self.smsButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SMS "))
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Canonical Addresses"))
        self.windowMainLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SQLite Android Database Parser"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Please Choose Data Parsing Option"))
        self.ViewDataCB.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Choose An Option"))
        self.ViewDataCB.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "SMS Evidence"))
        self.ViewDataCB.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Sim Card Evidence"))
        self.ViewDataCB.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Call Log Evidence"))
        self.ViewDataCB.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "Canonical Address Evidence"))
        self.ViewDataCB.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "Full Report"))
        self.viewEvidenceButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "View Reports"))
        self.evidenceViewingLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Report Generator"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Generate Report"))
        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.actionOpen_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionExit_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))

    # Event Handling Code Section

        # Event Handling to open Report Viewer Window
        self.viewEvidenceButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 360, 141, 31))
        self.viewEvidenceButton.clicked.connect(self.openReportViewer)

        # Canonical Addresses Button Event Handling function
        def parseCanonical():
            self.canonicalAddressesButton.clicked().connect(self.select_data())
        os.system('CanonicalAddressesParser.py')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: what is your function `salect_data()` ? also `os.system('script.py')` will be called when you call `retranslateUi`

Comment: select_data() is the function in CanonicalAddressesParser.py, the script that parses the actual data. I am trying to call that from a click of a button. I dont want it to run the CanonicalAddressesParser.py script automatically when the gui script loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is opening the script as soon as you run the GUI is that you have this call `os.system('CanonicalAddressesParser.py')` under the retranslateUi function, so it is called along with everything else.  Also, you set you button up inside of a function that is never called.  And the button seems to be connected to a function that doesn't exist (or is at least not included in the code you posted).  You have also incorrectly set that button up.  The button click event that you set up just above it is correct though.

I would recommend creating a function called `select_data` and move the script running line to that function, then call it from the button.

```
def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    # Code here
    self.canonicalAddressesButton.clicked.connect(self.select_data)

def select_data(self):
    os.system('CanonicalAddressesParser.py')
```

Comment: The function select_data() does exist. It is in CanonicalAddressParser.py

Comment: Well you can change the name of the `select_data()` function in my answer.  I thought you were just trying to run the CanonicalAddressesParser.py script with the button click?

Comment: select_data() is the name of the function in the CanonicalAddressesParser.py script. This function does all the parsing of the data that I need. So I think that using your suggested solution above may work. I will try these solutions and report back.

Comment: @MalloyDelacroix change `def select_data():` to `def select_data(self):`

Comment: I managed to get it working by doing: self.canonicalAddressesButton.clicked.connect(self.select_canonical_data)

    def select_canonical_data(self):
        os.system('CanonicalAddressesParser.py')

Answer (score 0):

I think `os.system('CanonicalAddressesParser.py')` is not what you search for.
If your script `CanonicalAddressesParser.py` is in same folder than your main script, you can import it like that `import CanonicalAddressesParser`.
Then to call a function inside `CanonicalAddressesParser` you need to write : `CanonicalAddressesParser.func()`

So if you replace

```
self.canonicalAddressesButton.clicked().connect(self.select_data())
```

by

```
self.canonicalAddressesButton.clicked.connect(CanonicalAddressesParser.select_data)
```

Does it help ?

Comment: If you execute that code at least you will get an error indicating that the signal is not callable.

Comment: @eyllanesc, you're right, I forget to remove parenthesis on copy/past, but the code work without them, I just edited it.

Comment: I prefer the @MalloyDelacroix solution.

Comment: @eyllanesc it is not calling the function select_data() in the script, it is calling the script himself. Assuming the script call explicitly the func, it works, if not, nothing happen.

Comment: both solutions are correct in that sense, if you look at the author's code that library matters, but also calls it with os.system(), the author seems to not understand what he is doing.